# show data-id to <select> boostrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

i have problem to show data-id to  with bootstrap. it won't show the value dynamically when i click the button, and needs to refresh page between 2-3 times to change the value (refresh).

here is my code

```
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="#modal-form-edit" rel="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" > Edit</a>
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="#modal-form-edit" rel="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" > Edit</a>
```

modal

```
<div id="modal-form-edit" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            .....
        </div>  
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Book list <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" data-width="100%" name="book" id="book" required="required">
                            <option id="book" value="" selected="selected"></option>
                            <option id="book" value="1" >book 1</option>
                            <option id="book" value="2" >book 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

js

```
<script>
 $('#modal-form-edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var books-id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
  $("#book").val(books-id);
 });
</script>
```

any wrong code at there?

thanks before for any help (sorry for my English)

Comment: `$("book").val(books-id);` missing `#` if using id or `.` for class

Comment: Why you are using same id named "book" to multiple?

Comment: How can be variable's name contain ` - ` ?? Dont you get any error?

Comment: you can give id to `select` tag only. no need to give to `option` tag also

Comment: you are giving `id` to options, remove that. Also create a fiddle.

Comment: edited. my real code already has `#`, i forget to put in here.  but there is not the point. thx

Comment: @num Why you are using same id named "book" to multiple?

Comment: Are you just trying to pass the value from the button to the selected option, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8a2c6za9/

Comment: Ok solved. the problem is, i use select2 (to change the select display). when i remove `select2_single` the code working well. thanks all for the reply. but how if i still use select2? any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this once,

```
$('.atag').on('click', function(e) {
     var books = $(this).attr('data-id');
     $("#book").val(books);
 });
```

I have given saperate class, and variable declaration is wrong ,`-` is considered as `minus` use `_` instead.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1143/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#modal-form-edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var books_id = $(this).data('id');
  $('.select2_single option[value="'+books_id+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
 });
```

Comment: variable declaration has error. [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/3163/).
To get alert replace `-` with `_`.